# Spring bidirectional mapping infinite loop with fetchtype lazy

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, lombok

I have this inside User entity

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "role_id",nullable = false)
private Role role;
```

then Role entity

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "role",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
```

But this cases somehow infinite json loop.

I use lombok @Getter @Setter and @Accessors(chain = true) inside both classes

Comment: Since there is a cyclic reference you cannot serialize/deserialize objects of those class. If using Jackson, put @JsonIgnore on users property inside Role entity.

Comment: @vincendep , i tough fetchtype lazy is going to take care of it.. I dont want to get role users list everytime i want to fetch user entity

Comment: I think you are mixing serialisation and persistence. FetchType. Lazy means only that the association will be loaded from the database when needed (when the relative getter is called). So if you fetch the Role entity from the database and then call the getUsers accessor (note that jackson by default use getters when serialising private properties), you will have an object that cannot be serialized because it contains a cyclic reference.

Comment: So when I use @JsonIgnore it wont fetch Role users , not only so it wont include it in json?

Comment: JsonIgnore only tells Jackson to ignore that property when serialising/deserialising. So it doesn’t matter if it is a jpa association and if it has been fetched or not.